# how to use different IDs for one Element in CSS

Tags: css

I want to display 3 different *rollover image* on mouse hover over of 3 different`<a>` element. For this i have use following mechanism but this doesn't solve any purpose. this is as follows:-

```
 #item1 a {
    position: absolute;

    background-image:url("../images/step1_without_rollover.gif");
    }

#item1 a:hover 
    {
        position: absolute;

       background-image:url("images/step1_rollover.gif");
```

}

```
#item2 a{
        position: absolute;

    background-image:url("../images/step2_without_rollover.gif");
```

}

```
#item2 a:hover {
    position: absolute;

    background-image:url("../images/step2_rollover.gif");
```

}

```
#item3 a{
        position: absolute;

    background-image:url("../images/step3_without_rollover.gif");
```

}

```
#item a:hover {
    position: absolute;

    background-image:url("../images/step3_rollover.gif");
```

}

NOTE: i have only begining knowledge of CSS. it is registration process classified into 3 steps.

Thanks !!

Comment: Please suggest me the suitable way to perform this.. Thanks !!

Comment: i'm afraid that's not possible without using JavaScript

Comment: When asking questions, it's always best to think: "If I were trying to answer this question, what would I want to know?" In this case, as the CSS has to apply to markup, it would be pretty important to see the markup. Also, taking the time to clean up the CSS to make it readable will encourage people to try to answer the question. (You can do that with the "edit" link under the question.)

Comment: I don't think I completely understand your question, but you can't have 3 different images for a hover state. Hover state means that either the mouse is over the a tag or not. That means that you can only have 2 states. Not 3. Hence you can't have 3 images for hover events.

Comment: @sarcastyx: Actually i have 3 steps that i want to user to follow, simply just to add some attraction (in my view point) i think that. i m agree that we can nly have 2 states that is i have also 2 different (total 3*2 images) for this purpose

Comment: @NiksBestJPro, if you have 3 steps and want to change the image for when a user moves through the steps, and it is the same page that has all the three steps, then you will need to change the images using javascript. If there are three different pages, then you will need three different ID's or a way for CSS to identify which page the user is on and display that image. Also remember that ID's must be unique on a page as Jose Faeti mentions below.

Comment: @Sarcastyx: sir, I m implementing a registration process, that i have classified in 3 steps that are as follows-> 1) introduction, (2)contact information, (3) security. These steps are listed on a page, that links to other pages. i have set your caution point in my mind firmly :).. thanks so much.. for your quick response. :)

Comment: UPDATE+NEW QUERY-> @Sarcastyx: sir, i have implement the same as you describe except a change made on the top of code. However it shows the Last one image in all 3 three steps (images). i could not able to figure out why it display the *last one image* only

Answer (score 1):

you have some unnecessary css codes there. See the code below. It hopefully does what you want. Try cleaning up your css codes a little before you post. that being said, I still dont understand why you need 3 image rollovers though..hope this helps

```
#item1
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 492px;left :190px;width:400px; height:140px;
    }       
    #item1 a {
    background-image:url("images/image1.gif");
    }
     #item1 a:hover 
    {
    background-image:url("images/image2.gif");
    }
```

Comment: Thnx sir this code help me to display image hover effect for one image only; in the case  of 3 different id it display last one image only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you asking in the question, anyway remember that you cannot have more than one ID in the same HTML element, or the same ID in more than a HTML element. IDs must be unique.

**EDIT**
As much as I know, achieving 3 different background-image changes to the same element using only a :hover state is not possible using only CSS. You need JavaScript to give the element or its parents different classes when you want the image to change.

Comment: actually i want to display 3 (hover) images for 3 steps (that are linked to some web pages)

Comment: By 3 steps you mean 3 different pages or 3 steps on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I understand your point better now. So you have all the 3 steps on the same page. This means that you cannot have the same id 3 times on the page. You can do something like this though:

**Edit**

So you have three different pages. This means that you can use `item1` id on all the different pages. But your stylesheet will still need to understand which page it is. You could wrap the `item1` div around another div that has a different classname and then style it accordingly. If you go this way then this is what you will need to do:

HTML for Page 1:

```
<form class="page1" ...>
<div id="item1">
<a href="#">Step 1</a>
.....
</div>
</form>
```

HTML for Page 2:

```
<form class="page2" ...>
<div id="item1">
<a href="#">Step 2</a>
.....
</div>
</form>
```

HTML for Page 3:

```
<form class="page3" ...>
<div id="item1">
<a href="#">Step 3</a>
.....
</div>
</form>
```

And your stylesheet will look as follows:

```
#item1
{
position: absolute;
top: 492px;left :190px;width:400px; height:140px;
}
.page1 #item1 a {
background-image: url("images/image1.gif");
}
.page1 #item1 a:hover 
{
background-image:url("images/image1_hover.gif");
}
.page2 #item1 a {
background-image:url("images/image2.gif");
}
.page2 #item1 a:hover 
{
background-image:url("images/image2_hover.gif");
}
.page3 #item1 a {
background-image:url("images/image3.gif");
}
.page3 #item1 a:hover 
{
background-image:url("images/image3_hover.gif");
}
```

Or there is another way where you can use JavaScript to analyse the page and then change the background image based on that.

Comment: i'm afraid that i could n't find page class but as i m an developer on microsoft.net technologies, there is some `<form id="fomr1" runat ="server">` tag. so may i know that, is page class is equal to `Form id` or `form1`.  Thanks!!

Comment: @NiksBestJPro, Do you have forms like that on all the pages? And are they using the same `id`? Oh and it would be helpful if you could post some of your HTML code so that we can have a look at what is going on.

Comment: yes sir, i have the web forms on all the pages.. and they are using the same ids for same type of formatting there. There is `regProcess.html` source code ` <html> <head> <link rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/decorations1.css"/>
</head><body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id = "wrapper"> /*and other code goes there*/ </div></body></html>` Other pages also have the same form id name as form1, if i add another there than IDE will add up another automatically. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sarcastyx sir: actually i can 't understand by the meaning of .pages class. if you could explain me a bit about .page class than i m sure it will not be difficult to understand your point explained in updated answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @NiksBestJPro, you can give your form element a classname. That classname will help your stylesheet decide which styles to apply to the proper `a` tag. And I just found that I had a mistake in my answer with calling the right id's. I will update that.

Comment: @Sarcastyx sir: Xavier has solved this query but i m willing to understand the detail in short of this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## html

```
<div id="items">
<a href="#" class="item1">Item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="item2">Item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="item3">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

## css

```
#items
{
position:absolute;
top:490px;
left:190px;
width:400px;
height:50px;
}

#items a.item1
{
position:absolute; 
display:block; 
height:50px; 
width: 400px; 
top: 490px; 
left:242px; 
background:url("../images/step1_without_rollover.gif");
}
#items a.item1:hover
{
background:url("../images/step1_rollover.gif");
}

#items a.item2
{
position:absolute; 
display:block; 
height:50px; 
width: 400px; 
top: 490px; 
left:242px; /* don't forget to change your left value */
background:url("../images/step2_without_rollover.gif");
}
#items a.item2:hover
{
background:url("../images/step2_rollover.gif");
}

#items a.item3
{
position:absolute; 
display:block; 
height:50px; 
width: 400px; 
top: 490px; 
left:242px; /* don't forget to change your left value */
background:url("../images/step3_without_rollover.gif");
}
#items a.item3:hover
{
background:url("../images/step3_rollover.gif");
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, i have implemented your suggestion but this type of style declaration for `<a>` element, cover all of the presence of `<a>` </pre> element which i dont want to disturb.

Comment: i m sorry, i could not understand you what do you want to explain to me about adding up id around the styles/markup.

Comment: what you can do is: `#item a{ style }` and then for each a give it a class with different styles, so for example `#item a.one{ style } #item a.two{ style }`

Comment: Hello sir.. i followed your step but i couldn't find the desired output. `   #item a 
    {
      position:absolute;
      top:490px;
      left:190px;
      width:400px;
      height:50px;
    }                                                            #item1 a.one:hover
{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width: 400px;
  top: 490px;
  left:242px;
  background:url("../images/step2_ro.gif");
           }` and similar `style` declaration for other `id` such as `item2 a.one{style}` and `item3 a.one:hover{style}` ...

Comment: i have changed all the code you should be able to use it as a copy and paste solution now.

Comment: @Xavier sir, your given code is running fine... however it is vibrating instead of normal roll over effect, i could not figure out this but i have put same code given by you. If you don't mind i would like to have a little bit explanation about this code. Thanks again :)